# List of tables is not displaying with the \listoftables

Tags: tables, pdftex

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
...
...
...
\begin{tabular}{c||c|c}
            \title{Transition }
            $\delta$ & authorized (1) & unauthorized (0) \\ 
            \hline \hline
            MainDoor & PasswordCheck & MainDoor \\ 
            PasswordCheck & MainHall & MainDoor \\ 
            \end{tabular} ........

...
...
...

\end{document}
```

With the above code I am not getting the table in list of tables, List of Tables is empty.
**What is missing?**

Comment: Your example does not contain a `table` environment, so as far as LaTeX is concerned, there are no tables. Typically you'd have a `table` environment surrounding the `tabular`, and also containing a `\caption{}` (not `\title{}`) and possibly a `\label{}`.

Answer (score 3):

not only `\begin{tabular}` but `\begin{table}` should be used like below:

```
\begin{table}[h]
            \begin{tabular}{c||c|c}
                $\delta$ & authorized (1) & unauthorized (0) \\ 
                    \hline \hline
                    MainDoor & PasswordCheck & MainDoor \\ 
                    PasswordCheck & MainHall & MainDoor \\ 
            \end{tabular} 
            \caption{Transition Table of Automated Door}            
\end{table}
```

Doing this \listoftables will display the number of tables.